# How can 2 variable NOT be equal when they look equal in PHP?

Tags: php

I have eperienced a very strange issue and I can't get my head around it.

I actually have 2 value which PHP says are NOT equal, when they do equal in my eyes.

I have 2 variables:

```
$pattern = array('/index/' => 'index');
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$array_key = array_keys($pattern);

echo $array_key[0];
echo $uri;
```

Actually, when I echo both of these, I get the exact same text in my browser:

```
/index/
```

However if I do the following:

```
if ($array_key[0] == $uri) {
 echo 'Equals';
} else {
 echo 'Not Equals';
}
```

It ALWAYS gives me that they do NOT equals.

I do not know why is this, but my mind is kinda messed up right now. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: One of them may be followed by whitespace.  Use `var_dump()` instead of `echo` and view the page source. You'll see the whitespace in the page source, plus you'll get the string length.  There are a few other reasons too. The place to start is by debugging and inspecting them more deeply.

Comment: The browser does various things to text it renders, whitespace compression chiefly among them, encoding makes a difference too. As such, it is a terrible place to visually debug your strings. You must at least start with the page source.

Comment: There is no whitespace in it actually. I have already checked that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (trim($array_key[0]) == trim($uri)) {
 echo 'Equals';
} else {
 echo 'Not Equals';
}
```

Comment: I have did this, but same result. Nothing changed actually :/

Answer (score 1):

If the code says they are not equal, they must be not equal.
Change

```
echo $array_key[0];
echo $uri;
```

to

```
echo "X" . $array_key[0] . "X";
echo "X" . $uri . "X";
```

I am pretty sure you will see difference.

Answer (score 1):

try `strcmp($array_key[0],$uri)`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP there are kind of null value strings that doesn't print on an echo. See this excample:

http://3v4l.org/qY1au

$val1 has a \0 at the end of the string, but the printed value of var dump doesn't show an empty string at the end. Comparing it to a similar looking string returns false. String length output of var_dump shows that $var1 has more chars than $var2.

Only after using the trim function the value comparation returns true.

You should check if one of your strings contains something like \0.

You should check